# setText() inside Fragment inside FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a FrameLayout in my app that houses multiple fragments.
I have made a Bottom navigation and it all works well but I need to update TextViews in one of them and I can't get it to work no matter how far I dig on the net.

What I do in the onCreate is this: (it's not going to stay in onCreate, this is just for now to see if it works)

```
        Fragment fr = new HomeFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr).commit(); //show the fragment
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        HomeFragment hfragment = (HomeFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("HOME");
        hfragment.updateMoneyMonth("hello"); //set the text
```

My fragment is this:

```
private static final String TAG = "HOME";
    TextView moneyMonth;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: fml ");
        moneyMonth = v.findViewById(R.id.moneyThisMonth);
        return v;
    }
    void updateMoneyMonth(String text){
        moneyMonth.setText(text);
    }
```

I have no idea what is wrong since a lot of the tutorials I have seen have made this exact thing that I have.
I also saw a lot of people use id instead of a tag, how do I add an id to a fragment? When it's in FrameLayout?

Sorry if this seems kinda dumb or just the solution is super easy, very new to fragments.

Comment: are you calling your fragment from your parent activity of fragment?

Comment: Well you mean that I have my fragment that exists then I make the fragment from the MainActivity yeah? If so then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass data to fragment that you want to display on the Textview

```
 Fragment fr = new HomeFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
 fr.setArguments(args);
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fr).commit();
```

In your Fragment's onCreateView method, get the string from the Bundle and set to TextView as below -

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
 container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
    moneyMonth = v.findViewById(R.id.moneyThisMonth);
    moneyMonth.setText(value);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Well it works now, however, my app uses a timer and every second updates 3 TextView's. They do update on the onCreate() method but afterwards, I do args.putString("one of the three keys", "a value"); in a number of functions that are called from the timer. At the end I have a function that does  `fr.setArguments(args);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr).commit();` This for some reason doesn't update the fragment. How do I update the TextView's in the fragment every second with new values in the args? Also: Bundle and fr are set outside the onCreate

Comment: If it works for you, You can accept this as answer.